# Parse PGobject in Groovy

Tags: postgresql, groovy, jsonb, katalon-studio

I'm trying to parse selected result from PostgreeSQL in Groovy, but something goes wrong, when I'm trying to parse it.
I used a lot of things, but I haven't reached the goal.
I've tried so:
I have three columns in postgre. One of the columns (document) is jsonb type and I want to parse it.

```groovy
//instance of connection string to postrgre    

PgAdmin pg = new 
List<GroovyRowResult> result = pg.getSelectResult(Here goes select script)
for(Map oneRow in result) {
    def document = oneRow.get("document")
    println documnet //Well from here it works good, it prints jsonb data stored in document column.
    def customerName = document.get("CustomerName") // it failes and goes on error, where CustomerName is inside jsonB.
}
```

I've also tried to use JsonSlurper, but it also fails. 
[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: how should groovy parse something if you don't?

Comment: please edit your question and show how `document` looks like. try to `println document.getClass()` to understand the type of `document` variable.  also show the error that you have in current code and when you are using `JsonSlurper`

Comment: i found simple  solution , i just cast "select document::Text..." in postgre